# Hatching in a circle and outside a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to graph two circles on the same page so that the x-axes of both graphs are aligned and the y-axes of both graphs are the same height. (Maybe the appearance of these would not look nice with x-axes aligned.) The first circle is to have radius 3, and the second circle is to be dashed and to have radius 5/4; not to waste space, the scaling on the first graph is to be less than the scaling for the second graph. Maybe include five tick marks along axes a unit apart in first graph and three tick marks a half-a-unit apart in second graph. I would like diagonal hatching for shading. In the first graph, shading should be inside the circle, and in the second graph, shading should be outside the circle. (I looked on page 217 of tikzpgfmanual.pdf for drawing diagonal hatch lines. They are not there. Please indicate how to separate hatch lines.)  I included some of the suggested code. I did not find a manual for including tick marks on the axes.  When shading, do you usually include arrows on axes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}


\begin{document}


$\{(x, \, y) \mid \vert x^{2} + (y - 1)^{2} \vert \leq 3\}$ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[<->] (0,-3) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}


$\{(x, \, y) \mid x^{2} + y^{2} > 5/4\}$ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the *second* `tikzpicture` is actually the *first* circle, that you're referring to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it something like this what you want to achieve?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand\drawticks[1]{
\foreach \Valor in {-#1,...,#1}
  {
  \draw ([yshift=2pt]\Valor,0) -- ([yshift=-2pt]\Valor,0);  
  \draw ([xshift=2pt]0,\Valor) -- ([xshift=-2pt]0,\Valor);  
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style={
  fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1pt
  }
]
\begin{scope}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]
\draw[<->] 
  (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[<->] 
  (0,-5) node (yaxisl1) {} -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\fill[pattern=north west lines,opacity=.6,draw] 
  (0,1) circle [radius=3];
\node[anchor=north] 
  at (yaxisl1.south) 
  (label1)
  {$\{(x, \, y) \mid \vert x^{2} + (y - 1)^{2} \vert \leq 3\}$};
\drawticks{4}
\node[dot,label={left:$(0,1)$}]
  at (0,1) {};
\draw[thin] 
  (0,1) -- node[below] {3} ++(45:3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\clip
  (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2.2);
\fill[pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.6]
  (current bounding box.north west)
  rectangle
  (current bounding box.south east);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\draw[dashed,fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=5/4];
\draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-2) node (yaxisl2) {} -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
\node[anchor=north] 
  at (yaxisl2.south|-yaxisl1.south) 
  {$\{(x, \, y) \mid x^{2} + y^{2} > 5/4\}$};
\drawticks{1}
\node[dot]
  at (0,0) {};
\draw[thin] 
  (0,0) -- node[above] {$\frac{5}{4}$} ++(45:5/4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Each graph is nice. They are missing the tick marks. 1010011010 gives the code for these. Is that what you use? I would like to have arrowheads at both ends of the axes, too. I wanted both graphs in the same row - with the heights and widths (of the pictured axes) the same.  Since the radius of the first circle is much bigger than that of the second circle, and since the circle with the bigger radius is centered at (0,1), there has to be some scaling for the first graph. (The graph of the circle that you provide is centered at origin.)

Comment: 1010011010 gives the code to label each graph.  "\draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] (firstaxis) {$y$};  \node [above=0cm of firstaxis.north] {$\{(x, \, y) \mid \vert x^{2} + (y + 1)^{2} \vert < 3\}$}; May you explain the syntax to me? I have not seen "(firstaxis)" in the code for labeling a node. What is "above=0cm of firstaxis.north" instructing TikZ to typeset?

Comment: @user143462 please see my updated answer. Is something like that what you need?

Comment: @user143462 In `draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] (firstaxis) {$y$}; \node [above=0cm of firstaxis.north] {$a$};` The first `\draw` draws a line with arrow tips on both ends (due to `[<->]`) from `(0,-4)` to `(0,4)` and places a node called `firstaxis` at `(0,4)` with the label `$x$` to its left.

Comment: @user143462 The second path places a `node` 0cm above of the north anchor of `firstaxis` with the label `$a$`.

Comment: @user143462 In my updated answer I introduced the modifications you suggested in comments and additionally I added some marking of the radii (this clarifies the situation, since otherwise the different scaling might produce confusion).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!  Thanks.  I see your comments explaining some syntax. Please clarify the syntax for the following commands in your code.                                    \draw[<->]  (0,-5) node (yaxisl1) {} -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\fill[pattern=north west lines,opacity=.6,draw]            (0,1) circle [radius=3];  What is "node (yaxisl1){}"?  You don't have "\node (yaxisl1){}". You have "yaxisl1". Is the "l" for left? I guess you don't need "1". Why do you have "{}"? In "opacity=.6,draw", does .6 refer to the distance in points between hatching lines? Why do you need "draw"?

Comment: \node[anchor=north] at (yaxisl1.south) (label1){set};                                                                                                                        In this command, you have the optional argument "anchor=north". What is this telling TikZ to print? You also have ".south". I guess this is instructing TikZ to print the set below the y-axis of first graph. Why do you need "label1"?

Comment: @user143462  In `\draw[<->] (0,-5) node (yaxisl1) {} -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};` this `node (yaxisl1) {}` puts a node at the initial point, called `yaxisl1` (l for left 1 because I'll use a second such node for the other part of the picture) and with empty label; nodes must always have a label even if empty.

Comment: In `opacity=.6,draw`, the `opacity=0.6` gives the level of transparency (1 is completely opaque, = is completely transparent); `draw` is needed to draw the circle.

Comment: Comments are not the best place to discuss code. Please refer to the PGF/TikZ manual for a comprehensive explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I had this. Or did you want them aligned vertically? I used `landscape` option from `article` class to show them aligned horizontally.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FFbJT85.png?1]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,positioning,datavisualization, patterns}

\def\tickheight{2pt}
\def\tickamount{4}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\scope
\clip[xshift=9cm] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5)
      (0,0) circle (1);
\draw[xshift=9cm,pattern=north west lines,draw=none] (0,0) circle (3);
\endscope

\draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] (firstaxis) {$y$};

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];

\node [above=0cm of firstaxis.north] {First circle: $\{(x, \, y) \mid \vert x^{2} + (y + 1)^{2} \vert < 3\}$};

\draw[<->, xshift=9cm] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[<->, xshift=9cm] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] (secondaxis) {$y$};

\draw[xshift=9cm, dashed] (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];

\draw[pattern=north west lines,draw=none] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];

\node [above=0cm of secondaxis.north] {Second circle: $\{(x, \, y) \mid x^{2} + y^{2} > 1\}$};

\foreach \i in {-\tickamount,...,\tickamount} {
\draw (\i,-\tickheight) -- (\i,\tickheight);
\draw (-\tickheight,\i) -- (\tickheight,\i);
\draw[xshift=9cm] (\i/2,-\tickheight) -- (\i/2,\tickheight);
\draw[xshift=9cm] (-\tickheight,\i/2) -- (\tickheight,\i/2);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want. The center of the first circle should be (0,1). Look at the set. The radius of the second circle should be 5/4. Since the radii are quite different, I would like the distance between tick marks in the first graph to be less than half that in the second graph. The shading in the second graph should extend to the pictured Cartesian plane. So, it should look like a shaded square with a white circular center. Also, in the first picture, the axes should be extended a bit so that a tick mark is not at the ends. Please put the sets directly below the y-axis.  Thanks.